# NextGen Gallery + GalleryView by John Brien Plugins

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I've installed the NextGen gallery plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) and also the galleryview plugin by John Brien (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-nextgen-galleryview/) and wondered if anyone has used these plugins together. I've got my thumbnails running in a row underneath my main image and happy with this, but the plugin adds next and previous arrows to the left and right of the thumbnails (see image below) and I want to get rid of these and can't find a way of doing this.

[image: Next and Previous arrows to the left and right of thumbnails]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've looked through the css file and can't see anything in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the next and previous buttons by adding this to your custom css:

.nav-prev, .nav-next {
display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

You could try this plugin instead. It's more up to date.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-scrollgallery/